# continuity not working except for receiving calls, iMessages and AirDrop

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, copy-paste, continuity

for some reason the universal clipboard and handoff between apps stopped working but AirDrops, receiving and making calls on my Mac and iMessages continue to work perfectly.

I contacted Apple Support and we went through resetting the bluetooth adapter but it didn't work. I gave up on that because Apple support insisted log me out from iCloud on all my devices but I don't want to do that because this will force me to set-up banking apps and 2FA code generators from scratch.

Do you have a a suggestion that doesn't involve resetting the phone and the mac?

The phone ins an iPhone 6s and the Mac is a Macbook Air 2015. The OS versions are the latest. It might have stopped working after upgrading to High Sierra but I'm not sure about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is so hard to troubleshoot - I wish I had some good tips. Calls and iMessage probably are relying on APNS push notifications and AirDrop happens on demand - so you might have some blockage or delay in the full continuity system.

- Are you able to take the devices to a location where WiFi and Bluetooth are not congested like an empty field or a house with one Access Point?
- Are you confident Bluetooth works on the devices (and is ON)?
- Are you confident WiFi works on the devices (and is ON)?

Sadly, the “sign out of iCloud and/or reset all settings / erase all content and settings” ladder of escalated troubleshooting on iOS is likely the way you’ll get this fixed. But, you might lose any apps that aren’t available for re-download or downloaded on iTunes (if you have older apps that aren’t for sale anymore). Also, that three step process takes a lot of time for devices with 60 GB of iCloud content or more.

Sorry for the “non-answer” answer but I wanted to explain there is no good consumer level debugging or logs that are publicly documented to get at the root of what’s happening with continuity.

Comment: Bluetooth and WiFi definitely on and working on both devices as I have access to internet over WiFi and my bluetooth headphones work as usual.

Also, when I copy text on my Mac, the iPhone is aware of it because the paste menu stops working on the phone for a minute or so.